# JqGrid: make the width of rows auto shrink and grow depending on the width of browser viewport?

Tags: jqgrid

I am hoping that a JqGrid occupies all the width it is given, and it auto shrinks and grows depending on the width of browser viewport. I am hoping to see the horizontal scroll bar as late as possible when the browser viewport shrinks.

I am playing with autowidth and shrinkToFit and combinations of them, but no success.

Am I doing it in wrong place?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Do you mean browser windows under "browser viewport"? Do you want to resize grid with shrinking after resizing of browser window?

Comment: @Oleg, thanks so much for your input. By b"rowser viewport", I mean browser window. Yes, I want to resize grid with shrinking after resizing of browser window. The same goes when the browser window gets wider. Thanks, again!

Comment: There are many answers which register `resize` event like `$(window).bind("resize", function () {...});`. Inside of event handler one calls `setGridWidth` with corresponding parameters (the second parameter of `setGridWidth` can force shrinking). It's the main part of implementation. There are some variations depend on outer layout of the grid and some other implementation aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this on my apps with jQGrid. Here are some of my grid settings:

```
autowidth: true,
height: '100%',
shrinkToFit: false,
```

Below the creation of my grid, I use the `window.resize` function of jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $gridName.jqGrid('setGridHeight', $(window).height() - 160);
    $gridName.jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(window).width() - 210);
});
```

I subtract `- 210` from the window's width to account for a left content area that is `210px` wide.

I subtract `- 160` from the window's height to account for a header content area that is `160px` high.

Comment: I found a possible better way than substracting hard-coded values. I put a wrapper DIV around the grid, and then find its width to update the grid. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: @curious1 that's a great idea! That way, if the other container's width/height changes, I won't need to update a hard-coded value

Comment: correct! Glad that we helped each other. I have a tough situation. It is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973731/jqgrid-can-i-know-which-action-button-is-clicked-in-onselectrow  Do you happen to know of any solution?

Comment: @curious1 It looks like Oleg solved that one for you... he is a godsend for jQGrid questions - he helped me through many of my issues a couple years ago when I first started with jQGrid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68281788/why-my-jqgrid-is-shrinking-while-i-change-the-question-type I am facing completely different issue. In my case whole table width is shrunk.