# Why my JqGrid is shrinking while i change the question type?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

My Question Type contains options: Option, Textual and Value. I have added a functionality in JavaScript that whenever I choose Option in Question Type I get table below the form.  When I am retrieving data directly from the database with Question Type = Option then it is showing table that is fine but when I change my Question Type from Textual or Value to Option for other data, then JqGrid is getting shrinked automatically.
[image]

```
 function QuestionTypeChoice() {
                if($("#dropdownQuestionType").val()=="Option")
                    {
                        $(".GridDiv").show();
                    }
                else
                    {
                         $(".GridDiv").hide();
                    }
                $("#tblSurveyOption").jqGrid({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Survey/GetSurveyOptions",
                datatype: "json",
                async: false,
                postData: {
                    questionId: $('#SurveyQuestionsId').val(),
                },
                colNames: [
                   "Id", "SurveyQuestionId", "Sequence", "Option", "Description"
                ],
                colModel: [
                    { key: true, name: "SurveyOptionId", index: "SurveyOptionId", editable: false, hidden: true },
                    { key: false, name: "SurveyQuestionId", index: "SurveyQuestionId", editable: false, hidden: true },
                    { key: false, name: "Sequence", index: "Sequence", editable: true, width: 10 },
                    { key: false, name: "OptionValue", index: "OptionValue", editable: true, width: 40 },
                    { key: false, name: "Description", index: "Description", editable: true, width: 50 },
                ],
                pager: jQuery("#divSurveyOption"),
                rowNum: -1,
                scroll: 0,
                height: $(window).innerHeight() - 450,
                width: '100%',
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "Question List Options",
                emptyrecords: "No records",
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                autowidth: true,
                loadonce: false,
                gridview: true,
                multiselect: false,
                autoencode: true,
                ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
                gridComplete: function () { },
                ondblClickRow: function () { }
            }).navGrid("#divSurveyOption", { edit: false, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: false },
                {},
                {
                    // add options
                    zIndex: 100,
                    url: "/Survey/CreateOption",
                    mtype: 'Post',
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    closeAfterAdd: true,
                    width: 400,
                    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                    serializeEditData: function (data) {
                        data["SurveyQuestionId"] = $("#SurveyQuestionsId").val();
                        return $.param(data);
                    },
                    beforeSubmit: function (posdata, obj) {
                        if ($('#Sequence').val() == '' || $('#Sequence').val() == undefined) {
                            return [false, "Please enter a sequence"];
                        }
                        else if ($('#OptionValue').val() == '' || $('#OptionValue').val() == undefined) {
                            return [false, "Please enter a option"];
                        }
                        else if ($('#Description').val() == '' || $('#Description').val() == undefined) {
                            return [false, "Please enter a description"];
                        }
                        else if (CheckSequence(posdata.Sequence)) {
                            return [false, "Sequence number already exists"];
                        }
                        else {
                            return [true, ""];
                        }
                    },
                    afterComplete: function (response) {
                        if (response.responseText) {
                            var isSuccess = response.responseText.split('~')[0];
                            if (isSuccess == '1') {
                                toastr.success(response.responseText.split('~')[1]);
                            } else {
                                toastr.error(response.responseText.split('~')[1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    // delete options
                    zIndex: 100,
                    url: "/Survey/DeleteOption?questionId=" + $('#SurveyQuestionsId').val(),
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    closeAfterDelete: true,
                    recreateForm: true,
                    msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this?",
                    afterComplete: function (response) {
                        if (response.responseText) {
                            var isSuccess = response.responseText.split('~')[0];
                            if (isSuccess == '1') {
                                toastr.success(response.responseText.split('~')[1]);
                            } else {
                                toastr.error(response.responseText.split('~')[1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
        ReloadOptionGrid();
    }

    function CheckSequence(sequence) {
        var data = $("#tblSurveyOption").jqGrid("getCol", "Sequence");
        if (data != null && data.length > 0 && data.indexOf(sequence) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function ReloadOptionGrid() {
        $("#tblSurveyOption").jqGrid('clearGridData');

        //Reload grid trigger
        $("#tblSurveyOption").setGridParam(
        {
            url: "/Survey/GetSurveyOptions" + "?questionId=" + $('#SurveyQuestionsId').val()
        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
```

Comment: It depend how yo do the logic with the select element. Moreover you create a grid and then immediately use clearGridData and immediate new reloading, which  I think do double things - this is not a good solution. One more note - the width of the grid can not be percentage as you do - it can be set only in pixels. The autowidth do what you want - i.e 100% of the parent element.

Comment: By  any chance, do you have any idea how could i resolve the issue. The table is working fine when Option is already choosen

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: 4.4.4 version of JqGrid